# Multi-language styles within a single element with CSS

Tags: html, css, multilingual, farsi

High. I am developing a simple website that contains multiple languages (English and Farsi to be exact).

Now I know how to define a style for each language separately if they are separated by elements (i.e. `<p>`, `<div>`, `<section>`, etc.). The way to do that would be something like this:

http://qnimate.com/css-for-multi-language-website/

But there are certain times that even a single sentence would contain both languages like this:
This sentence contains English and فارسی.

I want to somehow define the styles for each language (mainly font-family and other font styles) without manually overriding the style for each word of the language contained with the other.

Comment: The CSS and HTML itself can't even separate a number from a letter, so you need to wrap each language in a `span`, or one ... or add a script to do it for you, a one that does know language

Comment: Thank you @LGSon. What element would be best in terms that it would have minimal visual side-effect? For example a `<p>` is not suitable.

Comment: Use a `span`, it will act as it almost wasn't there

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: Ok, so I did, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS and HTML itself can't even separate a number from a letter, so you need to wrap each language in an element, or one ... or add a script to do it for you, a one that does know language (which I don't recommend)

A `span` would be the most suitable, which will let the text flow as if the `span` weren't there.